# Can anybody provide me exact answer of this how to insert checkbox checked value to textbox in ascending order?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can anybody provide me exact answer of this how to insert checkbox checked value to textbox in ascending order ?

Means if i check checkbox1 and checkbox3 then output in textbox ia 1,2

and if i check checkbox3 then checkbox1 then also output in textbox would be 1,2

I have asked this question ... previously but haven't found any exact working answer ...

Remember ,,, i have to use with 500+ checkboxes .... in asp.net(VB)

Comment: Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx might help a bit

Comment: How many accounts do you have? I would vote for deleting all if possible! At first glance i found these:
1.) http://stackoverflow.com/users/505338/squiti-team
2.) http://stackoverflow.com/users/504570/user504570
3.) http://stackoverflow.com/users/507785/user507785

Answer (score 0):

A little more information might be useful. Is this purely for the UI? In which case JavaScript via jQuery is probably what you need. Do the checkboxes AutoPostBack? In which case a server-side solution might be the answer, although client-side might still be appropriate even in this case.

Comment: The simple code i want .... when i check checkbox1 and then checkbox2 then in textbox it appear as 1,2 and if i again uncheck checkbox1 then the output in textbox is 1 and if i check checkbox2 first then checkbox1 then the output in textbox is 1,2 .......... all the digits are arranged in textbox in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your checkboxes in a ObjectModel.Collection(Of CheckBox) (here named myCol) Then during the loading make sure that you assign the hanler

```
For each chk as CheckBox in myCol
   AddHandler chk.CheckedChanged, AddressOf PerformCheckUpdate
End For
```

Then you can perform the checked changed action in the Sub

```
Private Sub PerformCheckUpdate(Byval sender as object, byval e as eventargs)
   Dim colResults as New ObjectModel.Collection(Of Integer)
   For each chk as CheckBox in myCol
      If chk.Checked Then
         colResults.Add(chk.Name.Substring(8))
      End If
   Next
   Dim intArray(colResults.Count - 1) as Integer
   For i as Integer = 1 To colResults.Count
      intArray(i-1) = colResults.Item(i-1)
   Next
   Array.Sort(intArray)
   TextBox1.Text = ""
   For i as Integer = 1 To colResults.Count
       TextBox1.Text &= intArray(i-1)
       If i< colResults.Count then
          TextBox1.Text = ","
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```

It is not the most elegant solution, but it should work.